# Folder does not exists when changing directory using jcraft.jsch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, lftp

I'm running on a Linux machine a Java program that uses jcraft.jsch library to connect to an external sftp server. The code looks like:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = null;
Channel channel = null;  
ChannelSftp c = null;

session = jsch.getSession(ftpUserName, ftpHost, ftpPort);
session.setPassword(ftpPassword);

channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
c = (ChannelSftp)channel;

fn = c.ls("/Inbox");
c.cd("/Inbox");  //-- this line throws an error
```

For some reason when I run the change directory command "c.cd" I get:

```
4: Folder not found: /drwxr-x--- 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Jan 01 1970 /Inbox
```

It is weird because the listing (c.ls) of that folder does not throws an  exception.

Furthermore, if I lftp from the command line  from the same Linux server I can cd without any problems.

[image]

The stacktrace points to a _stat method inside the cd method.

```
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2108)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1676)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:290)
    at BW_Utilities.ftp.test.testFtpJsch(test.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

The folder structure of the remote site looks like the following when I connect using Filezilla from my desktop:

[image]

I just executed the same Java code on my windows desktop machine and the cd command worked. (Windows machine runs JDK 1.6.0_29 while the Linux server runs JRE 1.6.0.27)

Does jsch relies on some other library at the OS level at the client side?

Any idea how to proceed to troubleshoot this problem?

important UPDATE

I was able to reproduce the error on my dev machine. It got to do with jsch versions being used. The linux server is using jsch-0.1.31 while the dev machine uses jsch-0.1.52. It seems that whatever is causing the error is already solved in version 0.1.52. Wooot! Wooot! Finally!

Thanks

Comment: You write `c.cd("/Inbox");`, but when you sftp in you do `cd Inbox/`. Have you tried excluding the leading slash in your `cd` call in java? `c.cd("Inbox");`

Comment: Just tried with "Inbox", "/Inbox", "Inbox/", "/Inbox/", "./Inbox".. all of them giving the same problem. Also tried different folders in the SFTP with the same results.

Comment: have you tried using the absolute path to the `/Inbox` folder instead of the relative one?

Comment: I think that "/Inbox" is an absolute path.

Comment: What is the SFTP server? Can you try to debug a call to `_realpath` from the `cd`? What is the input `path` and what does the server respond (the `i` and the `str` in the `_realpath`)?

Comment: From my windows machine (where the cd commands works), if I run the following line of code:                                                                                String realpath = c.realpath("/Inbox");                                                          The value of realpath end up being "/Inbox"

Comment: Also, if I run   int serverVersion = c.getServerVersion();  The value of serverVersion end up being 3

Comment: But I asked about `_realpath` call from the `cd` + What does `session.getServerVersion()` return?

Comment: I see you have solved it. Post your solution as an answer. Or delete your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to jsch version 0.1.52 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following.

```
fn = c.ls("Inbox");
c.cd("Inbox");
```

Comment: @user1261620 is your program running in the same directory as the directory named `Inbox`? What error did you get?

Comment: What is the purpose of running the above code and what can we achieve it?